# Is PHP the only popular language that mixes simple and associative arrays into a single type?

Tags: php, programming-languages

I'm doing a research on PHP and wondering if there any other commonly used programming langues that use an associative array for both simple indexed element storage and key-value functionality. Does it make PHP unique in this sense?

For example, a language like C# distinguishes clearly between a simple array and a map\dictionary\hash

```
T[] array = new T[];
Dictionary<T, S> map = new Dictionary<T, S>();
```

Meanwhile PHP makes no such distinction (at design time)

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3);
$map = array("one" => 1, "two" => 2, "three" => 3)
```

Comment: **[Unclear what help you need](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important "see: 'Why is research important?'").** Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell what problem you are trying to solve or what aspect of your approach needs to be corrected or explained. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @gnat I need help with information on commonly used programming languages, more specifically in the aspect of array types used by them as to whether any of them mix simple and associative arrays into one type as PHP does. Hope I made it clear.

Comment: The datatype of PHPs "arrays" are actually quite similar to javas `LinkedHashSet`. So yes, similar things exist, but I don't know if any other programming language gives that particular datastructure such a large role. It is a rather perverse choice imo.

Comment: There are dozens of languages with this feature, more or less. Javascript is one of the better known ones, but awk, rexx, lua... What's the point of the question?

Answer (score 4):

Lua too has this trait. Lua's [tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lua_%28programming_language%29#Tables) can be treated as both maps and arrays. (Internally, a Lua table is implemented by having two parts (the user isn't aware of this), the array part and the map part, so it's efficient.)

(JavaScript has some kind of this duality too: since every object can serve as a map, and every array is an object, arrays can serve as maps too. But, I think, the opposite isn't true: objects that aren't arrays can't serve as *efficient* arrays (please correct me if I'm wrong; maybe it's implementation-dependent?), so JavaScript isn't a candidate for you.)

Comment: Tried to make arrays serve as maps in JS http://ideone.com/K3t3tB Doing it wrong?

Comment: @Desmond: "length" is relevant for the array part only. I understand that PHP has count(), which also counts the map elements, so this is a feature that JS (and Lua too!) indeed lacks, but I don't think the absence of this feature (counting the map elements) is important enough to disqualify Lua/JS.

Answer (score 2):

"Popular" is in the eye of the beholder.  The [Rexx language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rexx) is very popular in the mainframe communities, and it has associative arrays (called "compound variables") as a first-class language element.